# issue using variable for Assertions in response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, assertion

If I have an endpoint that supports POST http method in JSON. Let's say i have a field called `user_id` which is a string.  So, I created a user defined variable `user_1 ="abcdef"` which would be the value I pass to this field in the request.

But when I try and create a JSON assertion for the response. I am trying to assert that the user_id in the response is equal to `${user_1}`. but my assertion fails due to the double quotes
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your assertion fails due to quotation marks I believe it would be sufficient to remove the quotation marks from the user defined variable.
2. Also if you're comparing values in "strict equals" mode I think you need to untick "Match as regular expression" box

   [image]

   as in this case JMeter considers your user defined variable as a [Perl-5 style regular expression](https://www.pcre.org/) and uses "match" function instead of simple strings comparison so you will need to escape at least [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
3. It might also be a good idea to consider switching to [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Assertion), [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) is more powerful language comparing to JSONPath, moreover it has standard and [TCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) so you have confidence that your JMESPath query will return the anticipated result while with JSONPath each vendor has its own "understanding" and set of features. See [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

use user_1 ="abcdef" without quotes and pass use value in json as  "user":"${user_1}"
[image]

[image]

[image]